# Safari HTTP status code -1001?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, xmlhttprequest

Not entirely sure what is happening here. I'm making the following AJAX call, in Safari it fails and returns status code -1001. However Safari seems to think the call has been successful, despite the fact it returns no data.

Opening the url in another window returns the correct data. I can't seem to find anything on this status code on Google, although one post did suggest that Safari has issues with calls that take a while to return.

```
 $.ajax({
        url : sponsor.url,
        async : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(result) {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                var offer;
                for ( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    offer = result[i];
                    sponsor.offers[offer.id] = {
                            'id' : offer.id,
                            'displayType' : offer.offerDisplay.displayType,
                            'status' : 'accept'
                    } 
                    console.log(offer);
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

I'm wondering if this might have something to do with the async:false? The call does take quite a long time to return because I am running this within my local tomcat instance. The call can take upwards of 10 seconds to return on my local machine, however in a live environment the call is near instantaneous.

Comment: Try omitting the `async` parameter (the default is `true`). I searched  _safari http status code 1001_ in Google and this was the first link: http://www.thestupidbox.com/blog/index.php/http-status-code-1001-in-safari-browsers/

Comment: I did read about that, however it is important for this instance for this call to be asynchronous. This data needs to be on the page before the next call can be made.

Comment: put the next calls in the `success` callback